# Openvpn connection times out whenever I try to connect to university intranet with given config file

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to use openvpn to connect to my schools intranet. They provide a config file that I have imported but whenever I try to connect the session times out. Does anyone know what the issue might be?[Logs from when I try to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehlOh.png)

Comment: I think you should ask (the department responsible for this in) your school about it.

Comment: I tried but they can't seem to get anywhere with it. Another reason why I came here to see if anyone has similar issues.

Comment: So the staff and your other schoolmates can use it fine?